# ASP .NET MVC, Windows Azure and SQL Geography

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, sqlgeography

I used [this](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-site-with-sql-database/) tutorial to create ASP .NET MVC Site which manages table of Persons.
Now, I want to add another table (with controller) which manage a table with SQLGeography type. EF 4.3 don't support SQLGeography, so if I use in the model It can't genrate all the add,update,delete forms and methods. The way I see it, I have two alternatives:

1. Create temproary table, Which VS knows how to generate (longitude and latitude as two doubles). Then, add trigger to the DB when Add/Update occurs to update it in the main table. (I use the SQLGeography as WebAPI therefore I don't care it will be shows as two doubles).
2. Don't use EF. If this is the right way, How should I do it? I Create Empty controller, and then use ADO .NET to add/update/delete?

I hope my question is understood, I'm have a hard time with SQLGeography.

Thank you!

Comment: Or you can use .NET 4.5 and EF 5 where geography is supported.

Comment: .NET 4.5 is supported by Windows Azure?

Another question, Should I add the new entity to the same DbContext like the old entity, or create two dbcontext?

Comment: You are right. Azure doesn't support .NET 4.5 yet.

Comment: So which method is better? the first one or the second one?